# Accessing php-fpm installed in a lxc container

Tags: nginx, php, nfs, php-fpm, lxc

Looking for a way to access PHP7-FPM in an LXC container and PHP5-FPM in an other while NGINX is installed on the host.
The idea is to serve https://www.example.com/ with PHP7 and https://www.example.com/old/ with PHP5.

Here is my conf for NGINX:

```
    location ~ /old/\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass   192.168.0.10:9000;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass   192.168.0.200:9000;
}
```

Extra: How can I share the PHP files to the LXC containers? Is NFS necessary?

Answer (score 0):

If your `PHP5-FPM` is installed at `192.168.0.10` and listening to port 9000, and `PHP7-FPM` is installed at `192.1680.200:9000`, your configuration is just fine.

Then you need to share the files from the host to guest. NFS is one option for this.